# Exporting to CSV results in #name?

Tags: excel, csv, formatting

I have an excel file where there are lots of fileds with value's in it. I have some values which are as shown below:

++++comme ca

Now when I convert this file to .csv, using excel 2010 it converts to =++++comme ca, by adding an equal sign and treating is as a formula and display #name?.

Do you have any idea how can I export to csv with the actual displayed values. I tried lots of things by saving it as xls and then doing it instead of xlsx. I even tried by converting the column to text formatting but that still didn't work

Any clues on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text formatting doesn't change the fundamental values in a field, that's just for display purposes. If you want to force something to be treated as plain text, you need to prepend the value with a `'`, e.g. `'++++ comme ca`. The `'` will tell Excel to **NOT** try to interpret the value as a formula or other special value - it'll just spit out the "string".

Comment: nice one, but one problem is I can't go over the whole excel sheet looking for this. It does it ocassionaly over the sheet. And it's huge sheet. Is there something else I can try that could save me time.